# The requested resource /qrcodes was not found on this server

Tags: laravel

When adding inventory in the table called qrcode the resulting output The requested resource /qrcodes was not found on this server.

```
public function store(CreateQrcodeRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $file = 'qrcodes/'.$qrcode->id.'png';
    $newQrcode = QRCode::text("message")

    ->setSize(4)
    ->setMargin(2)
    ->setOutfile($file)
    ->png();

    if($newQrcode){
        $input['qrcode_path'] = $file;
        $qrcodes = $this->qrcodeRepository->create($input);
        Flash::success('Qrcode saved successfully.');
    }else{
        Flash::error('Qrcode failed to saved successfully.');
    }
    return redirect(route('qrcodes.show',['qrcode' =>$qrcode]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The`view` should be inside `resources/views` folder instead of `public` folder

Comment: new output is    The qrcode path field is required.

Comment: I voted up your question and comments :-)  anyway more specific please. please take screen shot or write more text of your error.

Comment: i make controller by the name of QRcode controller the above information is the content of the controller and also i made a folder by the name of qrcodes inside the public folder now if i want to safe information in the QRCODES table the output in the php myadmin is : The qrcode path field is required.